# svn working copy spanning 2 physical drives?

Tags: svn, tortoisesvn

I have a large repository hosted on dreamhost that I backup daily on a remote machine using a windows scheduled task which updates the working copy located on an external USB 300GB drive connected to the remote machine.

The 300GB drive is nearly full with only 26GB of free space remaining.

Recently I added a second USB external 1TB drive to increase storage capacity.

I would like to ask: what is the best way to use the new 1TB drive?

1. Is it possible to span the working copy across both drives (ex: somehow create a 1.3 TB drive)?
2. If I copied the working copy from the 300GB to the 1TB would svn continue form
3. do I need to retarget the update working copy script to the new 1TB drive and start downloading everything again (least desired option)

thanks

Comment: Are you copying almost 300GB of your repository daily from Dreamhost?

Answer (score 0):

**Q:** 1. Is it possible to span the working copy across both drives (ex: somehow create a 1.3 TB drive)?
**A:** With third-party software, yes, but probably not a good idea. Better to use just one drive.

---

**Q:** 2. If I copied the working copy from the 300GB to the 1TB would svn continue form
**A:** Yes

---

**Q:** 3. do I need to retarget the update working copy script to the new 1TB drive and start downloading everything again (least desired option)
**A:** Depends on the script, does it reference the 300GB drive by drive letter or other means?